# Cannot access properties

Tags: java, spring, properties

I got a Spring MVC application. It runs over the Tomcat 7 server.

I want to make a props.properties file, so my app could access properties during Beans initialization process.

So i did the following:

1.Create a context-parameter to my web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>mainProps</param-name>
        <param-value>${catalina.home}/conf/props.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

2. I created a MainCobfig class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/racoonsoft/wish/properties/props.properties")
@Import({WebConfig.class })

public class MainConfig {
@Autowired
Environment env;

@Value("${db.host}")
static String dbHost;
@Value("${db.name}")
static String dbName;
@Value("${db.login}")
static String dbLogin;
@Value("${db.password}")
static String dbPassword;

@Value("${ozon.login}")
static String ozonLogin;
@Value("${ozon.password}")
static String ozonPassword;
@Value("${ozon.apiurl}")
static String ozonApiUrl;

@Value("${payture.apihost}")
static String paytureApiHost;
@Value("${payture.merchant}")
static String paytureMerchant;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor scheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public OzonProcessor apiProcessor() {
    return new OzonProcessor(ozonLogin, ozonPassword, ozonApiUrl);
}

@Bean
public PGSQLDataSource pgsqlDataSource() throws Exception{
    PGSQLDataSource result = new PGSQLDataSource(dbHost,dbName,5432,dbLogin,dbPassword,"org.postgresql.Driver","jdbc:postgresql:");
    result.loadSettings();
    if(FacebookController.dbProc==null)
    {
        FacebookController.dbProc = result;
    }
    //FacebookController.dbProc = result;
    return result;
}
@Bean
public PaytureProcessor paytureProcessor()
{
    PaytureProcessor proc = new PaytureProcessor(paytureApiHost,paytureMerchant);
    return proc;
}
}
```

3 - I created props.properties file and put it into /conf directory

When i start my application it didnt throw the exception (file not found) - so i beleave it sees the properties file. But during bean initialization my fields (dbHost,dbLogin etc.) are still null`s.

How can i put values from properties file to my fields?

Help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotated factory method of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` MUST be a **static** method:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

[Spring API Reference manual of @Bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) remarks this.

A little bit more detailed explanation:

This is because `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` (BFPP).
BFPP does a post-processing on the bean factory just before other (normal) beans are being instantiated and intialized. So, BFPP's are needed to be created in order to work, **before** the `MainConfig` *bean* is instantiated. Marking this factory method as a static method, we can invoke this method without instantiating `MainConfig`.

Comment: I made changes (updated code in question). But still have null values when pgsqlDataSource() is called...

Comment: Fields you are injecting with `@Value` annotation must **not be static**. Static fields are not targets of a placeholder processor.

Answer (score -2):

```
# form user login properties
userName.required = User Name is required
```

In controller side you declare only `userName.required`. That's how you declare it.